# Equiprobable model combinations

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

In a question in our statistics project, there is a set of balls, numbered $1$ to $10$, each ball is equally likely to be selected, making the sample space

$S = \{\{i, j, k, l\} : 1 \leq i, j, k, l \leq 10~\text{where}~i,j,k,l~\text{cannot be equal to each other}\}$

The size of the sample space is obviously $|S| = 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 = 5040$

But then we are asked to find the probability that at least one of the numbers on the four selected balls is less than $4$ (call it event $E$) *and* at least one of the numbers is even (call it event $F$).

I've found that the size of event E is $|E| = 3 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 = 1512$ because you only have $3$ choices for one of the balls, but then $9$, $8$, and $7$ for the others.

Then for event $F$, $|F| = 5 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 = 2520$ as there are only $5$ even numbers, so $5$ choices for one ball, and $9$, $8$, and $7$ for the others.

I want to find the intersection of these two events but I'm not sure how. Multiplying the probabilities wouldn't work as the two events are clearly not independent.

Thanks in advance, Ciaran

Comment: Are you collecting a subset of four balls from $S$?

Comment: Yes, and the balls are taken out, not replaced, giving the size of the sample space as 5040

Answer (score 0):

Since we are selecting a subset of four balls from a set of balls numbered from $1$ to $10$, the sample space is the set of all four-element subsets of that ten-element set, which has cardinality 
$$|S| = \binom{10}{4}$$

Event $E$ is the event that at least one of the numbers on the balls in the sample is less than $4$.  To find this probability, we subtract the probability that event $E$ does not occur from $1$.  The probability that event $E$ does not occur is the probability that all four balls are selected from the seven balls numbered at least $4$, which is

> $$P(\overline{E}) = \frac{|\overline{E}|}{|S|} = \frac{\binom{7}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$

Therefore, the probability that event $E$ occurs is

> $$P(E) = 1 - P(\overline{E}) = 1 - \frac{\binom{7}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$

Similarly, the probability, $P(F)$, that at least one ball is even is found by subtracting the probability that all the selected balls have odd numbers.  The probability that all the balls have odd numbers is

> $$P(\overline{F}) = \frac{|\overline{F}|}{|S|} = \frac{\binom{5}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$

Hence, the probability that at least one of the balls is even is

> $$P(F) = 1 - P(\overline{F}) = 1 - \frac{\binom{5}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}}$$

Trying to compute $P(E \cap F)$ directly is difficult.  Observe, however, that $E \cap F = S \backslash (\overline{E} \cup \overline{F})$.  The event 
$\overline{E} \cup \overline{F}$ consists of all subsets of four balls with numbers that are at least $4$ or that contain only balls with odd numbers.  In general, 
$$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$$
Observe that since the only odd numbers that are at least $4$ are $5$, $7$, and $9$, it is not possible to select four balls with odd numbers that are at least four.  Hence, $\overline{E} \cap \overline{F} = \emptyset$.  Thus, 
$$|\overline{E} \cup \overline{F}| = |\overline{E}| + |\overline{F}| - |\overline{E} \cap \overline{F}| = |\overline{E}| + |\overline{F}|$$
Hence, the probability that event $E \cap F$ occurs is 
\begin{align*}
P(E \cap F) & = P(S \backslash (\overline{E} \cup \overline{F}))\\
            & = \frac{|S| - |\overline{E} \cup \overline{F}|}{|S|}\\
            & = \frac{|S| - (|\overline{E}| + |\overline{F}|)}{|S|}\\
            & = \frac{|S| - |\overline{E}| - |\overline{F}|}{|S|}\\
            & = 1 - P(\overline{E}) - P(\overline{F})
\end{align*}
which is

> $$P(E \cap F) = 1 - P(\overline{E}) - P(\overline{F}) = 1 - \frac{\binom{7}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}} - \frac{\binom{5}{4}}{\binom{7}{4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

List the numbers thus (Why ?): $|\;1\; 3\; |\; 2\; |\; 4\; 6\; 8\; 10\; |\; 5\; 7\; 9\;|$

A little thought will tell you that combinations that do **not** satisfy the criteria are:

All odd, or all $>3$, thus $Pr = 1 - \frac{\binom54 + \binom74}{\binom{10}{4}}$